# Stream difference between Java 8 and 11

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-11, flatmap

Consider this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)
            .flatMap(i -> Stream.of(i, i, i))
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .limit(4)
            .forEach(i -> {});
}
```

The output in Java 8:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

And in Java 11:

```
1
1
1
2
```

Was this a bug or intended behaviour in Java 8 that was changed in 11?

The above code is just an example to demonstrate the different behaviours, but a more serious implication of the difference is that the following code prints 1,2,3 in Java 11 but goes into an infinite loop in Java 8:

```
    Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 10)
            .flatMap(i -> Stream.iterate(i + 1, j -> j + 1))
            .limit(3)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

laziness has changed in case of `flatMap`, until java-10, `flatMap` was never lazy. see [JDK-8075939](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075939)

Answer (score 10):

[`Stream.flatMap( )` causes breaking of short-circuiting of terminal operations](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8075939) -

it was a bug that was fixed starting from **Java 10**.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug but an optimization to make `flatMap` work in lazy mode.

One of the beautiful feature improvement I can see, as now I can use `flatMap` in Lazy way, with *almost fully supporting **functional composition*** rather than *just a chain of function execution (**if not lazy**).*

Functional composition is what really excite me every day when I start writing ***NEW*** Java code.

Maybe I'm late to the party..!! :P